# What is the short form of this compare variable code

Tags: javascript, numbers, compare, between

Is there a way that I can combine these two codes into one? I want to check if some variables are equal to 0 or equal to 1 or equal to 2 or greater than 2 and less than 5 or greater than 5. Should I write a code for each variable or I can write a code for all variables?

```
       <script>
   if (NRIRDL==0){
XRIRDL=0;
    } 
else if (NRIRDL == 1){
XRIRDL = 1;
    }
else if (NRIRDL == 2){
    XRIRDL = 1.8;
}
else if (NRIRDL > 2 && NRIRDL < 5){
    XRIRDL = 0.9 * NRIRDL;
}
else {
    XRIRDL = NRIRDL - 1;
}
 // code below is the same as code above, but variables are different.

if (NRIRDR==0){
    XRIRDR=0;
} 
else if (NRIRDR == 1){
    XRIRDR = 1;
}
else if (NRIRDR == 2){
    XRIRDR = 1.8;
}
else if (NRIRDR > 2 && NRIRDR < 5){
    XRIRDR = 0.9 * NRIRDR;
}
else {
    XRIRDR = NRIRDR - 1;
}
     </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by code for each variable or write a code for all variables?

Comment: I mean for example instead of this: NRIRDL ==0 , NRIRDR == 0, can I do this: NRIRDL || NRIRDR == 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, it can be written shorter with ternary operator and without multiple if conditions, check it out:

```js
function getValue(n) {
    return n >= 2 && n < 5 ? n * 0.9 : n == 0 ? 0 : n == 1 ? 1 : n - 1;
}

var var1 = 0; 
var var2 = 1;
var var3 = 2;
var var4 = 3;
var var5 = 5;
console.log(getValue(var1)); // outputs 0
console.log(getValue(var2)); // outputs 1
console.log(getValue(var3)); // outputs 1.8
console.log(getValue(var4)); // outputs 2.7
console.log(getValue(var5)); // outputs 4
```

Just use `getValue(n)` function: pass your variable and it will return needed value that can be stored into another variable like `var XRIRDL = getValue(NRIRDL);` or `var XRIRDR = getValue(NRIRDR);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    if (NRIRDL==0 || NRIRDR==0 ){
        XRIRDL=0;
        XRIRDR=0;
    } 
    else if (NRIRDL == 1 || NRIRDR == 1)){
        XRIRDL = 1;
        XRIRDR = 1;
    }
    else if (NRIRDL == 2 || NRIRDR == 2)){
        XRIRDL = 1.8;
        XRIRDR = 1.8;
    }
    else if ((NRIRDL > 2 && NRIRDL < 5) || (NRIRDR > 2 && NRIRDR < 5) ){
        XRIRDL = 0.9 * NRIRDL;
        XRIRDR = 0.9 * NRIRDR;
    }
    else {
        XRIRDL = NRIRDL - 1;
        XRIRDR = NRIRDR - 1;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it into a function:

```
function yourFunction(val) {
  if (val == 0){
    return 0;
  } 
  else if (val == 1){
    return 1;
  }
  else if (val == 2){
    return 1.8;
  }
  else if (val > 2 && val < 5){
    return 0.9 * val;
  }
  else {
    return val - 1;
  }
XRIDR = yourFunction(NRIDR);
XRIDL = yourFunction(NRIDL);
```

When you OR the two inputs together, you lose valuable information about which one of the two inputs triggered that condition.

Mike's answer might not fit your needs because you can't update the values independently of one another (i.e. if NRIDR == 0 and NRIDL == 2, it sounds like you don't want both XRIDR and XRIDL to equal 1.8.)

Answer (score 0):

You could put it inside a function. Here's a copy paste of your code inside a function.

```
function xrirdr(dr_or_dl){
var XRIRDL = null;
if (dr_or_dl==0){
XRIRDL=0;
    } 
else if (dr_or_dl == 1){
XRIRDL = 1;
    }
else if (dr_or_dl == 2){
    XRIRDL = 1.8;
}
else if (dr_or_dl > 2 && dr_or_dl < 5){
    XRIRDL = 0.9 * dr_or_dl;
}
else {
    XRIRDL = dr_or_dl - 1;
}
return XRIRDL;
}
```

You can pass NRIRDL or NRIRDR in the function and it will get you your XRIRDL